# Angularjs templates: How to conditionally wrap a tag in another tag

Tags: angularjs

`ngIf` conditionally adds/removes a tag to the DOM.

But if I want to conditionally wrap one tag (eg content) in another (eg layout) what is the most *angular way* to do this?

Below is how I would do it in Handlebars

```
{{#if layout}} <div class="layout"> {{/if}}
    Content is always here, it is wrapped only if layout is specified
{{#if layout}} </div> {{/if}}
```

Comment: I think the whole scenario is outside of the Angular way of doing things. I'm sure you can achieve the same result using a fixed DOM structure.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not fully understand your end goal here, but it seems like it'd be invalid html .

Regardless, your best options would be to write a directive that builds your html for you.

If you're not comfortable with custom directives, then the easier implement would be **[`ngSwitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)**. It would let you set one way as the default, then you'll switch to the other one based on the expression that determines whether layout is to be wrapped or not.

Only thing I don't like about using `ngSwitch` in this type of case, it requires duplicating a bit of code. In this case it's very minimal.

If you have to do this throughout your application a few times, it'd be worth writing your own directive to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind for this scenario, is using `ng-class` on the wrapping tag. It doesn't exactly do what you wanted since the wrapping tag will always be present in the DOM, but you can modify its behavior in CSS according to your conditions.